# Paginación en Django rest Framework no funciona

Tags: python, django, api, rest, djangorestframework

Estoy intentando corregir un error que surgió sobre la paginación de toda la API que estoy implementando,
el siguiente código representa el paginador custom que desarrollé:

```
class Pagination (PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 100
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
```

Lo siguiente es la clase que estoy intentando paginar:

```
class ListProducts(
mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,IsSavedRole)
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(~Q(stock = None))
    serializer_class = ProductsSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter]
    pagination_class = Pagination
```

Esta es la configuración que tengo instanciada en el settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS": "rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination",
   "DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS": ["django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend"],
   "PAGE_SIZE": 100,
}
```

y el resultado del endpoint es el siguiente:

```
{
   "count": 158,
   "next": "https://api-dev.osyva.com/api/v1/products/?page=2&page_size=1",
   "previous": null,
   "results": [{...}]
}
```

158 es el total de todos los registros existentes en la base de datos, por ende cada que se hace la solicitud, se está devolviendo todos los registros de la base de datos aunque esté el parámetro **next** existente en la respuesta del servicio...

¿cuál podría ser el problema y que podría hacer que eso pasara?

Answer (score 0):

En el json del response, la clave `"count"` es la cantidad de objetos en total, no los que se muestran por página. Puedes hacer la prueba poniendo en tu clase Pagination:

```
page_size = 2
```

Alli verás que `"count"` sigue siendo 158, pero te mostrará solo 2 registros.